# Installation of flash player for Slackware/KDE4/Firefox

Tags: linux, firefox, flash-player, kde-4, slackware

Help Please,

From the instruction in the readme.txt file that was with the download
sudo cp libflashplayer.so /usr/lib/firefox-15.0.1/browser/plugins 
sudo cp -r usr/* /usr

I have the lib file @:

sh-4.2$ ls -alu /usr/lib/firefox-15.0.1/browser/plugins
total 17044
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root     4096 Dec 23 12:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root     4096 Dec 23 12:27 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 17418724 Dec 23 12:27 libflashplayer.so

Tried every thing at this post:
[HowFlashplayer works](https://superuser.com/questions/609989/how-flashplayer-works-in-firefox-for-linux-flash-player-installation-troublesh)

Answer (score 0):

Basically I keep reading and found this:

[You are here: start » slackware » flashplugin](http://docs.slackware.com/slackware:flashplugin)

copied the file to $HOME/.mozilla/plugins

started working. I want to dig through that firefox code now!!!